# Spyne: How to handle iterables

Tags: python, json, django, rpc, spyne

I have a django application that accepts JSON requests, processes the requests, forwards them as SOAP to an API, processes the response, and then forwards the response as JSON to the client.

Methods that don't have Iterable in the response are working fine. But for methods that have an Iterable, it either returns a disarranged response or Internal Error.

For example:

```
class MyCitiesIterable(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    ID = Integer
    Description = String


class Other(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    Errors = Integer


class MyCitiesResponse(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    Cities = Iterable(MyCitiesIterable)
    Other = Other
```

Object returned:

```
(MyCitiesResponse){
   Cities = 
      (MyCityArray){
         MyCity[] = 
            (MyCity){
               Description = "City 1"
               ID = 1
            },
            (MyCity){
               Description = "City 2"
               ID = 2
            },
            (MyCity){
               Description = "City 3"
               ID = 3
            },
      }
   Other = 
      (Other){
         Errors = 0
      }
 }
```

JSON response

```
{ "Cities":
    [
         {
            "Description": "MyCity",
            "ID": [[["Description", "City 1"],
            ["ID", 1]],
            [["Description", "City 2"],
            ["ID", 2]],
            [["Description", "City 3"],
            ["ID", 3]]]}],
            "Other": {"Errors": 0}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you use `Array` instead of `Iterable`, does it work?

Comment: Can you please a sample service code and application code as well? The json response is weird, you have values for `ID` and `Description` swapped!

Comment: using `Array` returns the same response

Comment: Ok, but I still need to see more code. Please comment when you're done